# When using `this.$parent` in VueJS components is legit?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I am working on an app made with Vue JS. Despite I used props most of the time to pass data from a parent component to a direct child component, I just realized that sometime I accessed directly the parent data using `this.$parent` without a real reason.

Vue JS documentation says:

> [...] you cannot (and should not) directly reference parent data
> in a child component’s template

So why is it possible? Does this way provide some advantage in any very specific case?

If there is any situation when it's better to use `this.$parent` to access to parent's properties or methods, then I would understand how to recognize it.

Comment: It is not a strict rule to not use `this.$parent`. See https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Implicit-parent-child-communication-use-with-caution for full explanation

Comment: Thank you so much @VamsiKrishna, I missed that part of the documentation. It is a good explanation, however it doesn't contain examples of edge cases where prop mutation or `this.$parent` can be helpful, but only of the contrarian cases. Do you have any example for that?